# Suggestion for checking old value against new value and commenting

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

I am trying to compare a value in a table against a new value given in a form then giving a response of what was changed but it's giving the value if true or not

`$var1` (existing value in table pulled from a search to display currently value in the form)

`$var2` (new value provided in form)

`$comment1` (the response)

This is what it looks like now:

```
if ($data[var1]!='$_POST[var2]')
{
    $comment1="$data[var1] changed to $_POST[$var2]";
    // (this will be scrubbed but I have the simple form here)
}
else { $comment1=""; }
```

I have tried:  `if($data[var1]<>'$_POST[var2]')`

I have also tried adding `$old_var1=$data[var1];`
Then changing to  `if($old_var1]!='$_POST[var2]')  and if($old_var1]<>'$_POST[var2]')`

But the comment still shows if they are the same or not, I only want the comment to apply if they are not the same.

Comment: if var1 and var2 are string - try this: `if ($data['var1'] != $_POST['var2'])`

Comment: Frankly, learn the very basics first, you have no clue what you're doing. That code doesn't make a sense at all. It's better to know what you're doing that typing random characters and trying what it will be doing.

Comment: Why don't you, for example, check how "not equal" operator looks like in PHP [in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), instead of randomly trying various combinations of various characters? Programming is about thinking, not about "bruteforcing".

Comment: As @VasylZhuryk said, it's probably the `string` error.
But you should try debugging a little. Log the 1st value, then the 2nd value to see if they're the same of not. Once you figure out what the output is, you might find more to the problem.

Comment: Documentation showed both != and <> both working a not equal condition. Maybe you use a different doc than the one you linked?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the data value to a string that is `'$_POST[var2]'` but not the data inside `$_POST[var2]`

Try: `if ($data['var1']!=$_POST['var2'])` if your keys are **var1** and **var2**, or
`if ($data[$var1]!=$_POST[$var2])` if the keys are stored in repective variables

Comment: When I echo both var1 and var2 they show the correct response, what is already in the table and what was input in the form field.

Comment: let me try to put more info here maybe I am not explaining well<br><br>var1 is streetname, in the table streetname has a value of 'Ashland', so the actual check pulls var2 which is $data[streetname]  and calls it $old_street<br><br> the for form as streetname and when the form is submitted (leaving out the cleaning is $_POST[streetname] the if statement checks if $old_street against $_POST[streetname] and if there are not the same it should make $comment1 = '$old_street to $_POST[streetname]' <br><br>When i echo both they give the correct answer but same or not the comment ($comment1) shows

Comment: please edit your question with correct formatting, because i am not understanding this comment